# Create xml file in Silverlight class library

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I have project in which I want to create few files to save data. When I want to save this files I get action denied error, because my SL app dont have permission to save.

How can I save this file in class library project files or web ClientBin folder from other project code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create files from Silverlight, you should write to the IsolatedStorage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

You will have access to that folder, with a limited quota by default.